# d3.js How to target and change elements' attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm creating a bunch of Objects (using a pseudo-class, so they all have the same structure) with the properties "name", "type", "status", "poxitionX" and "positionY".

Then I activate my SVG drawing area using d3.js

```
var svg = d3.select("#d3canvas")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 600)
.attr("height", 400);
```

and draw my Objects as circles on the canvas

```
function drawCircle (objectHandle) {
var tempDrawVar = svg.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "white")
    .style("fill", "orange")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("cx", objectHandle.positionX)
    .attr("cy", objectHandle.positionY)
    .on("click", function(d){
        objectHandle.doStuff();
        });
}
```

doStuff() is a method / prototype function that is supposed to ask the user for input and react to the user input by changing attributes of some of the previously created circles.

The problem is, that I don't know how to "target" those circles. I can update the properties in the Objects just fine, but I really don't think completely deleting the canvas area and creating new circles with every "update" is anywhere near a decent solution.

I can't use tempDrawVar outside the function, and even if I could it would be overwritten each time a new circle is draw anyway (or is it? I'm not sure, I admit).

I tried creating an global Array, using the draw function's parameter as index and using that as the variable instead of tempDrawVar. The drawing function works, but the array stays empty...

```
var circleArray = new Array();

function drawCircle (objectHandle) {
circleArray[objectHandle] = svg.append("circle")
...
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? (In a nutshell: How can I create a function that targets a specific "item" created with d3.js and change one or more of its attributes?)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but `this` refers to the clicked on DOM element in your handler. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Bonus question: why didn't the array trick work? Was it flawed logic on my part? A stupid idea to begin with?

Comment: Lars Kotthoff: sorry, that's not what I'm looking for. I'm not clicking on the element I want to change. For this example suppose there is a big red "do stuff" button somewhere below the canvas that should change let's say to radius of one specific circle.

Comment: How do you identify that specific circle?

Comment: That's exactly my question. How DO I indentify it? I know I want to change the circle that represents my Object "foo". But when drawing it with d3.js it's not itentifiably as being foo's representation in the DOM. that's what I meant by "how can I target it".

Comment: Well, you could attach a class to it to be able to identify it, or you could use the data to match it with `.data()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for identifying specific elements. You can use a DOM selector, which means that you would need something like an ID or a class attached to the element to target it.

```
d3.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.class; });

// select DOM element for first data element based on ID
d3.select("#" + data[0].id); 

// select by class
d3.select("circle." + data[0].class);
```

Alternatively, you can use D3's data binding to do the matching. This relies on having a matching function that tells D3 how to match data to DOM elements.

```
// second argument to .data() is the matching function
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data, function(d) { return d.id; })
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

// select the DOM element for the first data element
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .data([data[0]], function(d) { return d.id; });
```

The latter is probably the more D3 way to do it, but more code (and not particularly nice code at that) to select the element. You also have to remember to pass the same matching function to `.data()` all the time.

In the example code you've posted, it doesn't look as if you're binding any data to the created DOM elements, so you would have to assign an ID or a class to be able to identify them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't notice that I can set an attribute "id" for the elements I create by adding .attr("id", objectHandle.name) to the function. You are also correct that I'm not binding any data. I'm very new to JavaScript (mostly used PHP until now) and was looking for a lightweight library I could use to draw stuff, and a friend recommended looking into d3.js.

Comment: You may find the tutorials at the D3 website helpful.